# how can i extract this text in python beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can i extract this text(which is summary starting from `<p>` to `</p>` in python beautiful soup?

```
<div>
      <div class="o-media__body">
          <span class="text-bolder text-larger">Summary</span>
      </div>
      <div>
           <p>Hello, I m from Europe Macedonia, I came to USA 12 years ago, i got my citizenship 7 years ago, I m very happy person, i like to help people, I don't like to change jobs.In my life I worked only 3 jobs, First job I worked as a Nurse in Macedonia for 7 years, and I had to leave as i came to USA. Then I found a job in Wisconsin as a teacher at the Day care, I worked there for 6 years, I had to leave as i moved to Reno, NV. In Reno I start working at Disability Attorney's office, we were helping people to apply for disability i worked there for 5 years, I like to go to work everyday, and i like to do my job right, if i don't understand something I will ask for help, I believe is better ask then make mistakes. I lost my job after i returned from my vacation, i don't know the reason, I have a good recommendation letter from my previous job.
          </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this but it is giving only summary as output

```
soup_data.find("span", { "class" : "text-bolder text-large" })
```

How to extract nested tags?

Comment: Can you post more of the sample html? The div tags are mismatching

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `select()` because i like the jQuery-like syntax, but it's just me.

Using the [URL from your comment](https://www.jobcase.com/p/zulejhazoey.ferati):

```
text = soup_data.select("div.panel-body > p")[0].get_text()
```

`text` will contain:

```
"Hello, I m from Europe Macedonia, I came to USA 12 years ago, i got my citizenship 7 years ago, I m very happy person, i like to help people, I don't like to change jobs.In my life I worked only 3 jobs, First job I worked as a Nurse in Macedonia for 7 years, and I had to leave as i came to USA. Then I found a job in Wisconsin as a teacher at the Day care, I worked there for 6 years, I had to leave as i moved to Reno, NV. In Reno I start working at Disability Attorney's office, we were helping people to apply for disability i worked there for 5 years, I like to go to work everyday, and i like to do my job right, if i don't understand something I will ask for help, I believe is better ask then make mistakes. I lost my job after i returned from my vacation, i don't know the reason, I have a good recommendation letter from my previous job."
```